# Empty string input with read system call causes Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, operating-system, segmentation-fault, system

I'm trying to read in input from STDIN using `read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);`
How should I handle cases when the input is EOF? Or empty string? Currently, I get a Segmentation Fault

Here is the code snippet:

```
int rd;
char buf[100];
rd = read(0, buf, 99);
buf[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code assumes the string contains `\n` bit that might not be true. Check the manual page for `read`. It tells you how many bytes it read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like all other string functions, [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn) relies on the string to be null-terminated to begin with.

If the input doesn't contain a newline, then the `strcspn` function will go out of bounds due to the lack of the terminator.

You also need to handle the case when `read` returns with end-of-file or error, which is indicated by it returning `0` or `-1` (respectively). Just as specified [in the manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) (which you really should read!).

Simply add the terminator directly after the `read` call at the appropriate position, but only if `read` succeeds:

```
rd = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof buf - 1);  // sizeof buf relies on buf being an actual array and not a pointer
if (rd == -1)
{
    // Error, handle it
}
else if (rd == 0)
{
    // End of file, handle it
}
else
{
    // Read something

    buf[rd] = '\0';  // Terminate string

    // Terminate a newline
    buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';  // Truncate at newline (if any)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped :)